# Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My Query-

`$shortlistpartners` is array

```
$this->db->delete('shortlist_partners');
$this->db->where('opp_id',$this->input->post('opp_id'));
$this->db->where_in('partner_id',$shortlistpartners);
```

Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause. 
error is coming,tell me any solution.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, CI [`delete()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L1520) method returns `no where or limit` error on:

From the **[Source Code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L1563-L1571):**

```php
if (count($this->ar_where) == 0 && count($this->ar_wherein) == 0 && count($this->ar_like) == 0)
{
    if ($this->db_debug)
    {
        return $this->display_error('db_del_must_use_where');
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

So I guess all you need to do is to swap your wheres with delete call:

```php
$this->db->where('opp_id',$this->input->post('opp_id'));
$this->db->where_in('partner_id',$shortlistpartners);
$this->db->delete('shortlist_partners');
```

Comment: not working for me..still getting the same error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289206/codeigniter-deletes-are-not-allowed-unless-they-contain-a-where-or-like-cl

Answer (score 1):

You have `--safe-updates` enabled, which doesn't allow `DELETE without WHERE`

For beginners, a useful startup option is `--safe-updates` (or --i-am-a-dummy, which has the same effect). It is helpful for cases when you might have issued a DELETE FROM tbl_name statement but forgotten the WHERE clause. Normally, such a statement deletes all rows from the table. With `--safe-updates`, you can delete rows only by specifying the key values that identify them. This helps prevent accidents.

Have a look a [**MySQL Doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates)

The quick fix is to add SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; before your query :

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

OR use `TRUNCATE TABLE_NAME;` if you need to delete all records from table.